# How to split /etc/nixos/configuration.nix into separate modules?

Tags: nixos, nix

Suppose I have a very simple [NixOS configuration file](http://nixos.org/nixos/manual/index.html#sec-configuration-file):

```
{ config, pkgs, ... }:    
{
  imports =
    [ # Include the results of the hardware scan.
      ./hardware-configuration.nix
    ];
  # SOME STUFF
  environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [ emacs gitFull ];
  # SOME STUFF
}
```

I know that NixOS implements a [module system](http://nixos.org/nixos/manual/index.html#sec-writing-modules), and a module is a `.nix` file. Every `.nix` file should contain any valid [Nix expression](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#chap-writing-nix-expressions) (e.g. a function or a set). This means that the NixOS configuration file `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` is itself a module, containing a Nix expression.

I also know that to make the Nix expression in another module visible to the module I'm working with, I can use a built-in [`import` function](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#ssec-builtins).

I want to split the declaration of system packages (the list containing `emacs` and `gitFull`) away into file `packages.nix`. How do I split the NixOS configuration file into separate modules?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

#### Nix expressions

A [Nix expression](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#ch-expression-language) is like any programming language expression: anything that evaluates to a value or a function. A value in this case can also be a list or a set. As a Nix module (file with extension `.nix`) can contain any Nix expression, you would expect the NixOS configuration file (`/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`) to contain a single Nix expression as its file contents.

The NixOS configuration file contains a Nix expression of the form:

```
{config, pkgs, ...}: { /* various configuration options */ }
```

If you look closely, you can see it's a [function](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#ss-functions), because functions follow the form `pattern: form`. You can also see it's a function that accepts a set and returns a set. E.g., if you have a function `f = {x, y}: {a = x + y;}`, then you could call it as `f {x=1; y=2;}` and get back a set `{a=3;}`.

So that means that when you call `nixos-rebuild switch`, something calls the function inside the NixOS configuration file with the set that must contain attributes `config` and `pkgs`.

#### imports

Following example of `./hardware-configuration.nix`, the simple way to extract the list of packages into a separate module `packages.nix` is just to rip the `environment.systemPackages` option out and put `./packages.nix` into `imports` option. Your `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` would look like:

```
{ config, ... }:    
{
  imports =
    [ # Include the results of the hardware scan.
      ./hardware-configuration.nix
      # Include the package list.
      ./packages.nix
    ];
  # SOME STUFF
  # SOME STUFF
}
```

Your `/etc/nixos/packages.nix` would look like:

```
{ pkgs, ... }:
{
  environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [ emacs gitFull ];
}
```

How does that work? When you run `nixos-rebuild switch`, the process that evaluates Nix expressions and decides to install packages and so on calls `configuration.nix` with a set of attributes, some of which are `config` and `pkgs`.

It finds attribute `imports` inside the returned set, so it evaluates every Nix expression in the modules that `imports` contains with the same arguments (`config`, `pkgs`, etc).

You must have `pkgs` as an argument (or, technically speaking, an attribute of a set, which itself is an argument) of a function in `packages.nix`, because, from a Nix language perspective, the process might or might not call the function with the set that contains `pkgs`. If it doesn't, what attribute would you refer to, when running `with pkgs`?

You also must have ellipsis, because the function might be called with other attributes, not just `pkgs`.

Why isn't there `pkgs` in `configuration.nix`? You can have it, but if you don't refer to it anywhere in the file, you can safely omit it, as the ellipsis would include them anyway.

#### Updating an attribute by calling an external function

Another way is just to make a function that returns a set with some attribute, and the value of that attribute you would put inside `environment.systemPackages`. This is your `configuration.nix`:

```
{ config, pkgs, ... }:    
{
  imports =
    [ # Include the results of the hardware scan.
      ./hardware-configuration.nix
    ];
  # SOME STUFF
  environment.systemPackages = import ./packages.nix pkgs;
  # SOME STUFF
}
```

Your `packages.nix`:

```
pkgs: with pkgs; [ emacs gitFull ]
```

`import ./packages.nix pkgs` means: load and return the Nix expression in `./packages.nix` and as it is a function, call it with an argument `pkgs`. `with pkgs; [ emacs gitFull ]` is a [with-expression](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#idm46912467576704), it brings the scope of the expression before semicolon to the expression after semicolon. Without it, it would be `[ pkgs.emacs pkgs.gitFull ]`.

Comment: How are imports merged? Do they use [recursiveUpdate](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/ff3f6f38c4735a921c71412ec55068fdd89addbf/lib/attrsets.nix#L413) or something like it?

Comment: Is there a way to do conditional imports?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai the value of `imports` is just a list, so you can append elements to that conditionally, e.g. `imports = [ ./foo.nix ./bar.nix ] ++ (if baz then [ ./quux.nix ] else []);`

Comment: In practice, conditional imports often lead to infinite recursion errors. You should import the file unconditionally and guard its configuration behind the condition using mkIf: `{ lib, ... }: { config = lib.mkIf condition { environment.systemPackages = ...; } }`

Comment: Be sure to add the file to git (if a git repo is used for `/etc/nixos`). Otherwise, one gets `No such file or directory` when adding another file to `imports`. -- Example output: `nix/store/8jmlyjs6dxq7yp8wjn8iyzcdlpi8y677-source/nix-alien.nix': No such file or directory`. The given directory contains a `configuration.nix` showing the most recent version, but the referenced file is not contained in the directory.